# 2D Java Arrays. Turning Negative numbers to zeros

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This method should input a 2d array of ints `(int[][])` and returns the 2d int array with all of the negative numbers replaced with zeroes.

For instance, if you send it `{{4,5,-6},{7,-8,9}}`, your method should return 
`{{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`.

```
public static int[][] zeroNegatives(int[][] arr)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<arr[r].length; c++)
        {
            if (arr[r][c] < 1)
            {
                arr[r][c]*-1;
            }
        }
    }
    return ;
}
```

I'm not sure how to return a 2d array or how to change the elements in a 2d array.

Comment: You wrote negatives should be replaced with zeroes but in your example, you return their positive values. Which is it?

Comment: What you want is an array with all **absolute values**. Zeros are different. I'm assuming you meant zero negatives as in no negatives. But you shouldn't say zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public static int[][] zeroNegatives(int[][] arr)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++) // Loop over array of arrays
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<arr[r].length; c++) // Loop over arrays
        {
            if (arr[r][c] < 0) // Check if negative
            {
                arr[r][c] *= -1; // "Change sign"
            }
        }
    }    
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: It's `int[][]` so it doesn't make a difference for the code, but really the test should be `< 0`, not `< 1`, just to be pedantic.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the array using `return arr;` i.e. your array passed as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and works**

```
public static int[][] zeroNegatives(int[][] arr)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < arr[r].length; c++)
        {
            if (arr[r][c] < 0) // if it's negative, it's less than 0, not 1
            {
                arr[r][c] *= -1; // it will equal itself multiplied by negative 1
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the description, **For instance, if you send it {{4,5,-6},{7,-8,9}}, your method should return {{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}.**

You would not to `repace all negative values as zeros`, `but to make it to a absolute value`.

And then return the arr directly.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] dataArray = { { 4, 5, -6 }, { 7, -8, 9 } };

    for (int[] array : zeroNegatives(dataArray)) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}

public static int[][] zeroNegatives(int[][] arr) {
    for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < arr[r].length; c++) {
            if (arr[r][c] < 0) {
                arr[r][c] *= -1;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
}
```

Output in Console:

```
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Additional, the following code change is not neccessary, but when the value is 0, it will not do 0 *= -1, such opeation is not neccesary.

Change if condition in second loop.

From

```
       if (arr[r][c] < 1)
        {
            arr[r][c] *=-1;
        }
```

To

```
        if (arr[r][c] < 0)
        {
            arr[r][c] *= -1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[][] zeroNegatives(int[][] arr)
{
int[][] method2DArr = arr;
    for (int r = 0; r < method2DArr.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<method2DArr[r].length; c++)
        {
            if (method2DArr[r][c] < 0)// for batter understanding use this, this is good way to write for negative.
            {
                method2DArr[r][c] = method2DArr[r][c] * (-1) ;
            }
        }
    }
    return method2DArr; //return reference.
 }
```

For batter understanding try this.

Simply return reference, not rocket science.

& if you want to srick with arr then also you can use

```
return arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try:

```
public static int[][] zeroNegatives(final int[][] array){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            array[i][j] = Math.abs(array[i][j]);
    return array;
}
```

`Math.abs(int)` returns the absolute value of `n`, which is the distance away from 0.